# TFS Authentication from another Domain

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, active-directory, trust

I need to have access to TFS from another domain. The problem is the following:

TFS --> domain A  (main company domain)

Visual Studio --> domain B  (development domain)

Domain A does not allow a trust between the 2.

Another solution would be to configure external authentication on TFS but it seems to require SSL an I don't have an SSL certificate.

Does anybody know a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a self signed SSL certificate and apply that to TFS. Once you have that, it isn't hard to tell windows to trust that certificate.

Use SelfSSL form the IIS Resource Kit to create the certificate. Then load the certificate into your root certificates store. [This blog explains it step by step.](http://www.leonmeijer.nl/archive/2008/08/01/123.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

thanks! So here's the steps:

- Make sure TFS 2008 SP1 is installed
- Download IIS 6.0 Resource Kit;
- selfssl.exe /K:1024 /K:1024 /V:7 /S:1
  /P:443

where the 1 matches with the
   site identifier in IIS ( you can see 
   the site identifier by opening IIS
   Manager, Click on the Web Sites node 
   and read the Identifier column from
   the item corresponding to your TFS install)